# Override JSON hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the context: I have a model and a controller, like this (very simplified, it's just for the example):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_json(options = {})
    return super({ :except => [ :id ] })
  end
end

class ModelsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    return @contact.to_json
  end
  def some_action
    return { "foo" => @contact }.to_json
  end
end
```

When I call the `show` action, the `Model`'s `to_json` action is called, and I have a json without the `id`:

```
 {"first_name":"Vincent",[...]}
```

When I call the `some_action` action, the result looks like this :

```
 {"foo": "<Model:0x000000048c7388>"}
```

How can have this response ?

```
 {"foo": {"first_name":"Vincent",[...]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `as_json` instead of `to_json`

http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a serializer library such as [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable).

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.9.3'
```

**Note the version!** Then create a `/app/serializers/contact_serializer.rb` that contains

```
class ContactSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :first_name
end
```

then in your controller, it's as simple as

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: @contact, root: false
  end

  def some_action
    render json: @contact, root: 'foo'
  end
end
```

Responses will then be

```
# show
{"first_name": "..."}

# some_action
{"foo": {"first_name": "..."}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of situations the best way to go is redefine the serializable_hash in the model, this way using the as_json method  it'll return a json with the definitions made in the serialazable_hash method. Something like this:

```
  class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    def serialazable_hash(options = {})
        options ||= {}
        options = {
          except: [:id]
        }.update(options)
        super options
    end
  end
```